# Modal not positioned correctly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I'm using ratchet to make a html mobile site. I've been using chromes device mode to test the app and the modal works as expected, it slides down and only covers half the screen but on ios and android it doesn't stay anchored to the top but slides on down to the middle.

the code is:

```
.modal.active {
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .25s;
    transition: transform .25s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s,opacity 1ms .25s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .25s,opacity 1ms .25s;
    transition: transform .25s,opacity 1ms .25s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

Can you see anything here that would make it act differently on a mobile?

Comment: modal slide down to the middle on mobile because of this `transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);` best bet is use media queries and put `modal.active` in media queries and change this property `transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);` according to the screen size

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution, use media queries to adjust the modal margin from top according to screen size

e.g

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {   
    .modal.active {
        height: 50%;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform .25s;
        transition: transform .25s;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,20%,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,20%,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,20%,0);
    }
}
```

[See in Action](http://jsfiddle.net/neLn1hbb/)

Comment: I changed the values to -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  and it now works